# How to generate SALT value in Java?

Tags: java, spring-security, salt

What's the best way to produce a SALT value in Java as a String that's at least 32 bytes long?

Comment: A salt value is just a randomly produced values.  What range of characters do you want?  Note: characters uses 2-bytes. Do you mean you want a `byte[32]` as a salt?

Comment: I wanted 32 random bytes encoded as a String as Shamim suggests.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
final Random r = new SecureRandom();
byte[] salt = new byte[32];
r.nextBytes(salt);
/** String encodedSalt = Base64.encodeBase64String(salt); */
```

Answer (score 3):

In SpringSecurity you can use `org.springframework.security.crypto.keygen.KeyGenerators`

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/keygen/KeyGenerators.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-security-crypto-keygenerators